# Applying Cross Apply & String_split to column - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

I have data in the following format unfortunately I'm powerless to how the data comes in, the data looks like;

| ID | Column X |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | I (a)Some Text (b)Some more Text (c) Text |
| 2 | 1a Some Text b Some more text c |

Is it possible to use Cross Apply and String split so data looks something like;

| ID | Column X |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | (a) Some text |
| 1 | (b) Some more text |
| 1 | (c) Text |
| 2 | a Some text |
| 2 | b Some more Text |

Ideally, the end goal once split will be to remove the a,b,c etc.

I'm using SQL Version; 2019 Dev

Comment: There's no consistent delimiter here. This is *not* a job for `STRING_SPLIT` but something outside of T-SQL's rudimentary string manipulation abilities.

Comment: There's nothing really consistant to go on here and any solution that works for the sample data as presented is at risk of not working in another circumstance. Are there always 3, or up to 3 data parts? Are they always preceded with a or b or c?

Comment: @Stu yes the data always appears in 3 parts so a b c in a way is the only consistency

Comment: It's probably possible then to engineer something specific but would require some cleansing of the strings first, although doable it's a complex process.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it appears in three parts. How do you tell the difference between `1a [some text q] b [y some more text] c` and `1a [some text] q [b y some more text] c`? Get your data cleaned up before you put it into a table. Something that formulated the string `1a some text b some more text c` knew that `some text` and `some more text` were separate values. Make that thing put some real and consistent delimiters between the values instead of just dumping garbage into the table. I solved this for you when the delimiters were at least consistent. This is a different level altogether.

Comment: @AaronBertrand many thanks for your help on my previous question your code worked for the 1a) example so I'll ignore the other formatted ones